# Why the .index and .timeindex files are consuming 10MB size?

Tags: apache-kafka

Please help me in the understanding of the below questions?

I have created one fresh topic with two partitions and not pushed anything into and found .index and .timeindex files are created for each partition, Also understood the concept of .index file. But want to know the reasons

1. Why those two files (.index and .timeindex) are created with 10MB size with some default data for an empty topic? How this default data will relate to the log file data?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Kafka documentation, this is due to the configuration `segment.index.bytes` from [topic level configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html#topicconfigs). It controls the size of the index that maps offsets to file positions. Kafka server preallocate this index file and shrink it only after log rolls. You generally should not need to change this setting.

Answer (score 0):

For the active segment, the entire `10Mb` `segment.index.bytes` are *allocated* by Kafka, which is why they show up as 10MB to the filesystem even though there is no data in there.

As soon as you roll the segment, they will be closed and the filesystem shows the actual size.

If you want to know more about the content of the `.index`, Strimzi has an excellent blog article about this: https://strimzi.io/blog/2021/12/17/kafka-segment-retention/